# Can I set a time limit for a code block?

Tags: php, php-5.3

Is it possible to start a block of code (maybe just call a function) and if it doesn't execute within a certain time skip it.

```
//give this function 10 seconds to execute
$value = mega_function();// could take anything from 1-1000 seconds
//if 10 seconds have passed and the value is still not set, abort it and set $value = false;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You would have to either

- Call the function inside an external file using curl or `file_get_contents()` - you can set a timeout there
- Keep track of the time inside `mega_function()` and `return()` if necessary.

What does `mega_function()`  do?

Comment: mega function is a program trying to interpret various blocks of text, so in order to get quicker results we just want to skip the ones that need more time for now, i guess I need to optimize code and probably use another language than php, but yea, got my tools

Comment: If it actually calls an external program, you can keep track of the time and kill the external process inside `mega_function()`

Comment: You may also launch a process from PHP, retrive the PID and relase the control. Then check until some seconds the PID status from an external script.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into threads, but it might be awkward to do something like this in PHP:)

Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php and all pnctl related functions for creating childs, sending signals between them, waiting for child to finish or killing threads.